# set time Count Down timer jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

How to set an EST time in a countdown using Javascript. I am using the following piece of code and able to set the hours countdown , but i need a particular time as
http://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20130920T1730&p0=152/

```
var now = new Date();
BigDay = new Date("September20,2013");
var countTo=BigDay.getTime()

 $('.timer').countdown(countTo, function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    switch(event.type) {
        case "seconds":
        case "minutes":
        case "hours":
        case "days":
        case "weeks":
        case "daysLeft":
            $this.find('span.'+event.type).html(event.value);
            break;
        case "finished":
            $this.hide();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You should really provide us poor code monkeys with some supplementary code, like your HTML at least so we can see what you're up to! :')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this along the lines of what you're looking for? First off, some HTML:

```
<span id="days"></span>
<span id="hours"></span>
<span id="minutes"></span>
<span id="seconds"></span>
```

Then, some Javascript (together with jQuery!):

```
setInterval(function(){
    // set whatever future date / time you want here, together with
    // your timezone setting...
    var future = new Date("Sep 20 2014 21:15:00 GMT+0200");
    var now = new Date();
    var difference = Math.floor((future - now) / 1000);

    var seconds = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

    var minutes = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

    var hours = fixIntegers(difference % 24);
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 24);

    var days = difference;

    $("#seconds").text(seconds + "s");
    $("#minutes").text(minutes + "m");
    $("#hours").text(hours + "h");
    $("#days").text(days + "d");
}, 1000);

function fixIntegers(integer)
{
    if (integer < 0)
        integer = 0;
    if (integer < 10)
        return "0" + integer;
    return "" + integer;
}
```

I hope this makes sense! [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLsP9/1/) if you'd like to see the live version in action.

You can also see this [Countdown Timer using jQuery](http://www.jweavers.com/posts/Making_Countdown_timer_using_jQuery.php)

Comment: Thanks. How can i make to work on firefox as well , this works fine on chrome.

Comment: Hey @user2619093, sorry bout that, I fixed the `future` variable initialisation, and it's working in Firefox now... ;)